# Style parent in android custom library is not found after being imported into a module

Tags: android, android-studio, import, styles

I converted an app module into a library and imported it to another app.
When I tried to build the app which contained the library, I got the following error:

**error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka xxx.yyy.zzz:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found**.

The following is the style which led to the error: (which is defined in the library)

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Besides, the theme specified in the main application is xxx.baseTheme:

```
<style name="xxx.baseTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
```

From the error message, it implied that **Theme.AppCompat** had been reparented to the package which used the library xxx.yyy.zzz.

Has anybody ever experienced this situation or has any idea about how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your main application's AppTheme ? can you please share the code?

Comment: @KGeeks
Yes, there is a default theme specified in the main application's manifest. 
```
 <style name="xxx.baseTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" />
```
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [android developer web page](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-library-dependency), I should have added the dependencies used in aar to the main module manaully. In my case which is androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).